How to reduce a region bound by a polygon/multigon in GEE?
I made a simple script trying to calculate average temperature from a user drawn polygon but I am failing to get the "geometry" of the polygon. How could this be done?
var Uusimaa = 
    /* color: #0000ff */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[13.200558303650775, 52.64869182887107],
          [13.200558303650775, 52.38461485070645],
          [13.66061079388515, 52.38461485070645],
          [13.66061079388515, 52.64869182887107]]], null, false);
          

// Download satellite imagery
var temperature = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GCOM-C/L3/LAND/LST/V1')
                .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-06-01')
                .filter(ee.Filter.eq('SATELLITE_DIRECTION', 'D'));

// Calculate the mean temperature for the specified region and time period
var meanTemperature = temperature.mean().multiply(0.02).clip(Uusimaa);

// Average temperature
var meanTempStats = meanTemperature.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: Uusimaa.geometry(),
  scale: 500,  // Adjust scale if necessary (500m resolution in this case)
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

// Convert to Celsius
var meanTempCelsius = ee.Number(meanTempStats.get('LST_AVE')).subtract(273.15);

// Print the result to the console
print('Average temperature in Uusimaa (2020-01-01 to 2020-02-01) in Celsius:', meanTempCelsius);


Managed to solve this myself. Here's the script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/286f57f084245497e033de041dd295ec
Edit: Shared code in a better way.
